# Regex to match substrings containing n non-repeated characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am facing a (naive) problem with regular expression.
I need to find any substrings composed of a fixed number (n) of different characters.

So, for "aaabcddd", if n=3 the substrings that I expect to find are: "abc" and "bcd".

My idea is to use n-1 capture groups and '[^' to exclude characters already matched. Thus, I wrote the following Perl regex (in Julia):

```
r"(([[:alpha:]])[^\2])[^\1]"
```

But, it is not working.

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use a backreference to a capture group using a negated character class `[^\1]`

What you can do is use a negative lookahead to assert what is directly to the right of the current position is not what you have already captured in a previous group.

If that is the case, capture a single alpha in a new group.

The matches `abc` and `bcd` are in capture group 1

```
(?=(([[:alpha:]])(?!\2)([[:alpha:]])(?!\3|\2)[[:alpha:]]))
```

- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `([[:alpha:]])` Capture the first char in *group 2*
    - `(?!\1)([[:alpha:]])` If not looking at what is captured by group 2 to the right, capture the second char in *group 3*
    - `(?!\2|\1)` If not looking to the right at what is captured by group 2 or 3
    - `[[:alpha:]]` Mach the 3rd char
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4f1CIe/1)

Or a bit shorter using a case insensitive match:

```
(?=(([a-z])(?!\2)([a-z])(?!\3|\2)[a-z]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to an arbitrary value of `n` characters:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use feature ':5.10';

my $s="aaabcded";
my $n=3;

while ($s=~/(?=([[:alpha:]]{$n}))/g){
    my $hit=$1;
    my @chars = split //, $hit;  
    my %uniq; 
    @uniq{@chars} = ();
    say "$hit" if (scalar keys %uniq) == $n;
}
```

Running with `$n=3` prints:

```
abc
bcd
cde
```

Running with `$n=4` prints:

```
abcd
bcde
```

And `$n=5`:

```
abcde
```